# Slideshow with music Control photoalbum like Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am searching for an Asp.net control like this one ,that can animate and make dynamically a slideshow with photos from database and music and then show in my asp.net page

Link here:
http://doctorbilic.com/cartea/

The above is coded in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Silverlight, then here is what you need:

These links are to source code to make a slideshow

- http://www.codeplex.com/SlideShow
- http://www.codeplex.com/SlideShow2

This link is to a blog entry on how to add sound to your Silverlight application

- http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/25/tip-of-the-day-22-how-to-add-sound-effects-music-and-video-to-your-silverlight-app.aspx

Using those together will get you what you want.

Also look at [this page](http://www.anixsoft.com/myslideshow/articles/create-web-slide-show-with-music/index.html).  They have a product that will do it for you (also in silverlight) for [about $50](http://www.anixsoft.com/order.html)

Answer (score 1):

This was done in Flash, actually. But you can try using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) with all its effects to achieve something close to that.